# When the depth of a conductor is sufficiently large, is the reactance equal to the resistance?

Tags: resistance, inductance, reactance, conductors

Is the reactance in a conductor approximately equal to the resistance in a conductor when the depth is very large?

If so, why?

I'm struggling to understand the concepts behind this. I believe it has something to do with skin depth.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "the depth"?

Comment: I meant the depth or thickness of the conductor if the conductor is rectangular.

Comment: Then what do you mean with "I believe it has something to do with skin depth"?

Comment: I thought that maybe the reactance was equal to the resistance because of the skin effect.

Comment: There is *a component* of reactance equal to resistance, which is a necessary consequence of skin effect being a diffusion process, i.e. R = X ~ sqrt(F). The *total* reactance of a conductor will almost certainly be higher due to reactance of the fields around it.  That is: the fields are not confined to within the material bulk itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is the reactance in a conductor approximately equal to the resistance
> in a conductor when the depth is very large?*

Not one bit. Reactance is related to inductance which in turn is related to how much magnetic flux is produced per amp of current. Resistance is related to the heat power loss due to current flow.

> *If so, why?*

It's not so, nothing to explain.